# Record bandwidth, page load and domComtentLoad data using JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-pagespeed

Is there any way using Javascript  (perhaps with an extension? ) to record  to an external file or by ajax the bandwidth, page load and domContentLoad load times according to URL being viewed?

Answer (score 1):

In the Network panel, right click in the grid and select "Save HAR with Content" to download the HTTP Archive file. You can alternatively click "Copy all as HAR" and paste it into your text editor.

[image: Network Panel]

In the HAR output, you can see the request and response headers in JSON format.

- The `DOMContentLoaded` value (in milliseconds) can be seen in the `onContentLoad` property of the `pageTimings` object (in milliseconds).
- The `Load` value (in seconds) can be seen in the `onLoad` property (in milliseconds).

I suspect the total transfer size and timings are calculated within DevTools from the individual entries in the HAR. You can easily calculate this by parsing the JSON and summing the relevant header values if need be.

[image: HAR 1]

An individual resource example would be the `kamalahmed.png` image download shown in the first screenshot above. It has a transfer size of 6.2 KB and downloads in 21 ms.

The `time` header, which is 20.601999... corresponds to the 21 ms (rounded) and

[image: HAR 2]

The `_transferSize` header, which is 6336 (in bytes) approximately corresponds to the 6.2 KB - possibly a minor rounding issue.

[image: HAR 3]

Comment: anyway to do this using JavaScript or to get Chrome to auto save the HAR file?

Comment: @Spencer You could check out the [PhantomHAR](https://github.com/cvan/phantomHAR) script for Phantom.js or use [chrome-har-capturer](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer), which uses the [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/)

Comment: The Chrome Developer Tools-> Network tab has the option to display an Initiator column. Is there any way to get the Initiator column data to be included in the HAR? Or to export the Name and Initator Columns from the Network tab activity?

Comment: @Spencer The `request` > `url` property will get the name, if you use some regular expression/string replace to get the ending.  The `headers` > `Referer` > `value` will get the Initiator, but it won't contain the line numbers. This is probably because the line numbers aren't relevant information to an HTTP log file.